# Custom prototype cell in UIStoryboard is created but doesn't show up in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a project where I need to use a custom UITableViewCell. I'm designing the cell as a prototype in storyboard and it looks fine there. I assign the prototype to my custom UITableViewCell subclass, give it the same reuse identifier I'm using in my UITableView and link the UILabel on the prototype cell to an IBOutlet in my UITableViewCell subclass.

When I call it from the UITableView the cell is created and if I add labels and buttons in the code of that class (create them with a CGRect and all) they all work but the labels I've added in the storyboard never show up.

I don't understand how my subclass can be called and created successfully but its layout and subviews from the storyboard don't seem to exist as far as my app is concerned. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you put your cellForRowAtIndexPath code mate ?

Comment: Better you refer http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/. This might help you.

Comment: @iOSNoob I edited the question with the code. Also, when I was searching for help before posting I found that link and followed it but I'm still having this problem and don't know why.

Comment: Are you using xib or storyboard ?

Comment: @iOSNoob Storyboard and a UITableViewCell subclass. I created a new project just to test this out, which is why there's so little code. I created the storyboard, set it up correctly (as far as I can tell) and my subclass is being used but none of the stuff I put on the storyboard shows up in the simulator when I run it.

Comment: Have you set set the “Identifier” of the custom cell to "MyTableViewCell" in  “Attributes Inspector” ?

Comment: @iOSNoob I set the identifier to "cell" and the class to MyTableViewCell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this issue before, and in my case, the problem was that the auto-generated code for the view controller included a call to:

```
[UITableView registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:]
```

I would suggest checking for and removing any calls to the above, or to

```
[UITableView registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:]
```

and trying your original code again.

Comment: I don't know how you figured that out but it's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your `cellForIndexViewPath` should look like this, to create a simple `custom cell` with label,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    } 
    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Make sure that you have made all connections well, set `datasource` and `delegate` to `table` and then set the “Identifier” of the `custom cell` to "MyTableViewCell" in “Attributes Inspector” like this,

**For storyboard:**

[image]

**Add "MyTableViewCell" instead of "SimpleTableCell" as shown in above screenshot.**

Comment: Can you modify this for a storyboard instead of a nib? In my storyboard I have a label on the cell but it doesn't show the text I've set in the storyboard or any custom text I set in cellForRowAtIndexPath. That label never appears in the simulator.

Comment: make connections to label in your MyTableViewCell class , and then access it to cellForIndexViewPath. As nameLabel in above code is my label in SimpleTableCell class.

Comment: Did both and made sure my identifier and connections were all correct but still nothing. I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: @acreichman: Check for Class in MyTableViewCell view. Click on MyTableViewCell view and then set this custom class as MyTableViewCell.

Comment: I've had that set from the beginning as well as the connections from the label on my prototype to the UILabel in my subclass and the reuse identifier on the prototype is the same as the one I'm using in cellForRowAtIndexPath. There's got to be something obvious I'm missing but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 0):

acreichman, add casting in cellForRow and put an NSLog in you cell's awakeFromNib to see if you get there. Let me know...

Comment: I added the cast and put an NSLog in awakeFromNib but neither fixed my problem and the NSLog never showed up in logs. But I'm not using a nib either, I'm doing it all in storyboard. I put an NSLog in my UITableViewCell subclasses initWithStyle and that does show up in logs so I know it's calling the right class, it's just not pulling anything from the storyboard even though I set the prototype cell class to my custom class

Comment: @acreichman initWithStyle will not get called because you're setting it up in storyboards, awakeFromNib will.  You should double check that the ReuseIdentifier and the class are set correctly (and that the cell is selected, and not it's contentView) and that in cellForRow you are addressing the correct identifier... just make sure because it's supposed to work.